# Xcode auto complete appears to be different and empty

Tags: swift, xcode

My xcode autoComplete looks weird all of a sudden. It is different to what I used to have. I was wondering if I accidentally changed a settings somewhere?

[image: xcode auto complete]

Comment: Yes the type information is missing, looks unusual, did you try a reboot?

Comment: have you recently updated Xcode? which version?

Comment: I didnt update my xcode. Rebooting didnt help. However, it is working now all of a sudden after I restarted the program a few times... very weird indeed

Comment: Did Xcode finish to index your code ?

Comment: I think it might be because the program was somehow stuck at indexing as @yageek suggests. Thanks